Deck with poor drainage -- any chance of salvaging it?
I'm about 90% certain the consensus is "replace it all" but would love to avoid that if possible and could use a sanity check. (And if we do replace it, how best to avoid repeating these mistakes.)
I bought a house in December with a huge (just over 1000 sq ft) deck that was built about ~20 years ago. The house is built on a hill that slopes away pretty aggressively, see pics for reference. The section close to the main body of the house is built on top of a concrete pad that served as the patio prior to this. They replaced a few deck boards right before I bought the house, and I was going to replace a few more before staining them but as I pulled some up the extent of the drainage problems became evident.
One major issue is the "spine" of the deck, where on one side they left a sizeable gap for drainage, and on the other it's at best 1/4" of an inch in size, but at worst reduces down to just about nothing. This side consequently got packed with dirt and is basically always wet, and unsurprisingly the joists have a bit of rot. They also put in some 2x4's horizontally that must have pooled water because they are in really rough shape. Other sections of the deck are in much better condition.
The other major issue is the aforementioned concrete pad section. They put down plastic sheeting prior to building presumably to aid drainage, but I popped the boards up and the joists are wet top to bottom, and there's an inch of dirt further impeding drainage. There's practically zero air flow potential under this section, and further complicating things is that pretty much the whole deck is heavily shaded so it takes ages to dry.
I modeled the house in SketchUp, here's a view of the deck.

View of the spine taken up:

Close up of where the spine was, annotated:

Lastly, this is a photo under the deck for the section over the concrete pad. You can see the joists are basically soaking wet, and there's no space under them for water to go. This was after removing most of the dirt. Surprisingly the joists aren't just disintegrating to the touch, but they're certainly soft.

Thanks in advance!

Replace all is probably not needed, but rebuilding from the bottom is.  Any wood you can push a pointy thing in much(more than 1/8 to 1/4) by hand, replace/cut off.  PT wood on the bottom will help and/or raising it up a bit.  Being so low, it is not a replace yesterday need/sprain ankle instead of a broken neck.

Plenty salvageable, (re-use the good lumber) and plenty showing that pressure treated wood has its limits particularly if it's not "ground contact rated" pressure treated.
